# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

So, I'm trying to use node modules with JavaScript and for that, I need to load the modules with "require", so I installed Require.js like so:

```
npm i requirejs
```

This is my code:

```js
var ecurve = require('ecurve') ;
var BigInteger = require('bigi')
var AES = require("crypto-js/aes");
var SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
```

However, I always get this error:

```
require is not defined
```

I've tried Browserify and solved the problem but I need another solution without Browserify. Any ideas?

Comment: how are you running the file? `node /my/file.js`?

Comment: you don't need `requirejs` when running a node application. `require` is built into node, so it sounds like you are not running the file properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would help you:

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for
>   in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments,
>   like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will
>   improve the speed and quality of your code.
>
> ```
> IE 6+ .......... compatible ✔
> Firefox 2+ ..... compatible ✔
> Safari 3.2+ .... compatible ✔
> Chrome 3+ ...... compatible ✔
> Opera 10+ ...... compatible ✔
> ```

http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Add this to your project: [download_me](http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js)

please go through [require.js docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html).

Comment: I 'd like to note for you that I was not the one who voted your answer down.

Comment: Ok, no worries. :)